# If T is a bounded linear map, what does $(T^\ast T)^{1/2}$ mean?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

If $T: H_1 \rightarrow H_2$ is a continuous linear map between two Hilbert spaces, $H_1$ and $H_2$, what does the notation $(T^\ast T)^{1/2}$ mean?  The book I'm reading defines $|T|$ to mean $(T^\ast T)^{1/2}$. ($T^\ast$ is of course the adjoint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T^*T$ is a positive operator (i.e., selfadjoint with positive spectrum). Such an operator is known to have a unique positive square root.

Comment: But what is the square root?

Comment: Given a positive operator $X$, there exists a unique positive operator $Y$ such that $Y^2=X$; we denote this $Y$ by $X^{1/2}$. The existence of $Y$ can be proven using functional calculus, the Gelfand Transform, or the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: Maybe the spectral theorem approach helps to understand the operator square root. Basically you define an operator with the same eigenvectors, but the original eigenvalues are replaced by their square root. ($T^*T = \sum_i \lambda_i ( a_i, \cdot )_{\mathcal{H_1}} a_i$ has the square root $\sum_i \sqrt{ \lambda_i } ( a_i, \cdot )_{\mathcal{H_1}} a_i$.)

Comment: Yes, only that in infinite dimension you may have no eigenvalues at all. But for sure it is better to understand this in finite dimension first.